# Distinguishing between Multiple jquery MultiFile uploads on the same Page

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I have an application page that requires multiple file uploads being performed on the submit button click event. For that purpose I'm using the [jquery multiple file upload plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/). However, one section for the uploads is for insurance purposes, while the other is for graphics, and a third is for supporting documents. How can i distinguish between the files uploaded from each section (i.e know that these files came from insurance file upload or from the graphics file upload section)? The implementation for the jquery multifile plugin is as follows for one file upload:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the HttpFileCollection
                HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;


                for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = uploadedFiles[i];


                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/ImgDetail/") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    }
                }
                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
}
```

However, the HTTPFileCollection does not distinguish which file upload component the file came from. Is there any work around this? I need to be able to tell which file upload the file came from so i can store the type of file accordingly in the database.

I am using Webforms with c# on Visual Studio 2010.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the way the files added to the HTTPFileCollection are in order based on the file upload elements order on the page. Thus, I limited the files for  each insurance and graphics to only one per file upload. As a result, the insurance file was found at index 0 of the HTTPFileCollection, whereas the graphics file was found at index 1. The rest of the files were supporting files.